# EAGLE 8.6 gives an ''std::runtime_error'' when running.

Tags: cad

I've recently had to install a new version of Autodesk's EAGLE software. I downloaded and unzipped it as I have every previous version, navigated to the install folder and ran `./eagle run` as I have every time before.

This time, however, it won't run and gives the error:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)`

From the limited other examples of this I suspect it's an ubuntu issue rather than an EAGLE one. However, I haven't seen any fixes. Using the LANG command to change to a UTF-8 language didn't do anything.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you have? Which session do you use - Wayland or Xorg?

Comment: I'm using 16.04LTS with Xorg.

Comment: I do not have autodesk acount, but login screen launches normally on  my 16.04 LTS. Unpacked and tested [this version](https://trial2.autodesk.com/NET17SWDLD/2017/EGLPRM/ESD/Autodesk_EAGLE_8.6.0_English_Linux_64bit.tar.gz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with v8.6.0 - I am running Debian 9 - The following fixed the issue for me:

```
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > sudo tee /etc/locale.gen
sudo locale-gen
./eagle run
```